# SMTP mail configuration for bugzilla installed on Apache in Windows

Tags: windows, email, smtp, bugzilla

I want to configure SMTP email which is in yahoo server for Bugzilla.

I have installed Bugzilla version 4.0 hosted in Apache server which is installed in Windows 7.

I have added the following details in the Email under Parameters within Administration:

```
mail_delivery_method = SMTP,
mailfrom = email_address,
use_mailer_queue = off,
smtp_username = email_address,
smtp_password = password,
smtp_debug = on,
whinedays = 7,
globalwatchers = email_address
```

How can I configure SMTP for Bugzilla?

Comment: Where is the question? You only listed what you did so far.

Comment: How can I configure SMTP for Bugzilla?